# "A generic error occurred in GDI+" after loading a PictureBox with an animated GIF

Tags: .net, winforms, picturebox

I have a Windows Forms application in .NET 2.0 with a PictureBox on a form and I load it with an animated GIF by setting the PictureBox's ImageLocation property. When it is time for the animation to render the next frame, I get the following exception and stack trace:

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension dimension, Int32 frameIndex)
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.ImageInfo.UpdateFrame()
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames()
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer, Boolean disposeEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at AIRNow.IMS.Mapper.MapWizard.Main() in C:\Projects\AIRNowI\IMS\UserInterface\MapWizard\MapWizard.cs:line 14
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why this happens, but I found a workaround. I had the PictureBox's WaitOnLoad property set to True. If I change it to False (the default) it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

mcdon's answer is close, actually even right. The thing is that if you let the `PictureBox` load the picture from the file named in the `ImageLocation` property, then the stream probably closes after the execution of `Load()`, but *before* all the frames were loaded (probably only the first frame loads). Thus you can avoid this if you load your picture manually to an `Image` object with `Image.FromFile()`, and give this object to the `PictureBox` through its `Image` property.

Answer (score 0):

I found a related problem dealing with multipage tiffs.  I use "pictureBox1.Load(fileName)", and then pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, index).  The call to pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame throws an exception "A generic error occured in GDI+".

The problem comes down to how the image is loaded.

When I load the image using:

```
Image _myImage = Image.FromFile(fileName);
```

and then assign it to pictureBox1:

```
pictureBox1.Image = _myImage;
```

The following call works properly:

```
pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, index);
```